# Purpose of the Cloud in IoT infrastructures

Tags: networking, connection, protocols, iot

My question is based on understanding generic IoT infrastructure.

Let's say I have a Wifi smart socket. My understanding is that upon pairing, the device communicates to the app via specific path (Device --> Local Router --> Manufacturer Cloud --> App) and vice versa for app-device communication.

Why is there a Manufacturer Cloud in the path? Why can't it be Device --> Router --> Some random telecommunication line --> App? In other words, why is there a middleman in the cloud?

Comment: I guess the manufacturer cloud may help the developers of the manufacturer get their apps running quicker. They may use an IaaS or PaaS solution to more quickly deploy apps on new virtual machines or containers.

Comment: Sure, but if I am worried about security, I'd rather send it straight to my app rather than route it through a cloud...I don't get why IoT solutions need a cloud

Comment: There are cloud environments that allow end to end encryption. From your device until your app. Which environment is your app running on?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. My question that I've been scouring the internet for an answer, is WHY nearly every manufacturer of IoT systems (Nest, Hive, Phillips etc.) routes data communication packets through their cloud. Why can't the Phillips app for example, communicate STRAIGHT to the device? You just need to encrypt the packet locally, send the packet over a standard transport layer, and then receive on the other end.

Why is there a Philips cloud server in the middle?

Comment: You may ask this question on http://iot.stackexchange.com with better chance for answers.